# C++ - Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

When dealing with multidimensional arrays, is it possible to assign two different variable types to the array...

For example you have the array `int example[i][j]` is it possible for `i` and `j` to be two completely different variable types such as int and string?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for:

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, int> > myData1;
```

or perhaps:

```
std::map<int, std::map<std::string, int> > myData2;
```

The first would require you to resize the vector to an appropriate size before using the indexing operators:

```
myData1.resize(100);
myData1[25]["hello"] = 7;
```

...while the second would allow you to assign to any element directly (and sparsely):

```
myData2[25]["hello"] = 7;
```

Comment: Note that the first form will be more efficient than the second, but efficiency isn't always everything. The second has big advantages in usability and extensibility. Also note that with `map` if you try to index something that doesn't exist, it will create it automatically with a default value.

Answer (score 3):

No. That's not possible. You may want to look into using the [STL map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/).

Answer (score 2):

No, C++ only allows integer types (ex: int, long, unsigned int, size_t, char) as indexes.

If you want to index by a string, you could try `std::map<std::string,mytype>` but it gets complicated trying to extend that to two dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you could use [std::maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28C%2B%2B%29).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can only use integer types as indices.

Comment: So you would have to use two separate arrays to do something like       student_name  and score

Comment: @Alec: what exactly are you trying to do? Do you want `array[name][score]` to access some third piece of data?

Comment: Blah, what i said made no since.. Sorry, I am trying to do that but gave a very poor example of what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You could achieve this with `std::map` though.