# How to define a 3d array with each dimension a different type in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, data-structures, stl

I want to define a 3D array like this:

```
Type ary[3/*enumeration type*/][6/*int*/][7/*const wchar**/];
```

Is it possible in C++? I'm using Visual Studio 2010, Boost library is not allowed. If it's possible, please tell me how to initialize each dimension?

Comment: so your each dimension have different type?

Comment: yes, it's so common in realistic lives.

Comment: it's possible in a way

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I think he expect each enumeration type will have int array associated with it and each int value will have wchar array.. thats why he is asking 3D array.

Comment: You can give a shot to std::map http://stackoverflow.com/a/3927754/2648826

Comment: That doesn't make much sense - could you explain how you would use it and how you expect it to work? I would claim that it's fairly *un*common in realistic lives to subscript an int to get a string. "The fourth element of 96 is 'foo'"?

Comment: @molbdnilo, in fact, it's as import as 3d array in C++. programmers can't live without multi-demensional array. because we can meet such complex data structures here and there.

Comment: @Triumphant Yes, there are complex data structures, but yours (whatever it's supposed to be) doesn't seem to fit with the array concept at all.

Comment: @Triumphant Well of course we all know what a 3d array is, but having dimensions of different types doesn't make any sense to me. How would you access such an array ? Like array[42][12.35f]["foo"] ? This kind of structure doesn't exist in C++, array indexes are always integral types. You should probably create your own data type to achieve what you want.

Comment: Do you want a `std::map<enum E, std::map<int, std::map<const wchar*, Type> > >` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible as it is because it is array elements of the same type.

```
struct s_i {
    int i;
    const wchar *wc[7];
};
struct s_e {
    enum Ex e;
    struct s_i i[6];
} ary[3];
```

Comment: can you initialize it in table-driven method?

Comment: @Triumphant I think I do not know the meaning of Table-Driven, but to be able to in the same way as an array.

Answer (score 2):

Following may help you:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename IndexType>
class typed_array
{
public:
    typedef typename std::array<T, N>::const_iterator const_iterator;
    typedef typename std::array<T, N>::iterator iterator;

public:
    const T& operator [] (IndexType index) const { return array[int(index)]; }
    T& operator [] (IndexType index) { return array[int(index)]; }

    // discard other index type
    template <typename U> const T& operator [] (U&&) const = delete;
    template <typename U> T& operator [] (U&&) = delete;

    const_iterator begin() const { return array.begin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return array.end(); }
    iterator begin() { return array.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return array.end(); }

private:
    std::array<T, N> array;
};

enum class E { A, B, C };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    typed_array<int, 3, E> a;
    typed_array<typed_array<int, 4, char>, 3, E> b;

    //a[2] = 42; // doesn't compile as expected. `2` is not a `E`
    b[E::A]['\0'] = 42;
    //b[E::A][2] = 42; // doesn't compile as expected. `2` is not a `char`

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible.

What you *can* to is to make a class that behaves as an enumeration and has a subscript operator which returns another special class (that in general behaves as an `int`) which has a subscript operator which in turn returns the `wchar_t` array.